# How to do onkeypress in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement a input tag that only allows numbers to be put in.

One way that I found work is the following

```html
<input name="num" 
   type="number"
   pattern="[0-9]*" 
   placeholder="Enter new PIN" 
   onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
   title="Numbers only">
```

But I would like to change `onkeypress` for an angular function. Is there anything that can work similar?

I have tried `(keyup)`, and `(change)` but neither work the same. They allow the key to be pressed then remove the number.

```
<input (keyup)="checkPin($event)" 
  type="number" 
  pattern="[0-9]*" 
  placeholder="Enter new PIN" 
  inputmode="numeric" 
  style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"></input>
```

Here is the TS function `checkPin`

```
checkPin($event: KeyboardEvent) {
  console.log($event)
  let value = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;

  if ($event.target) {
    if (value == "") {
      value = value.slice(0, 0);
    }

    if (value.length > 4) {
      value = value.slice(0, 4)
    }
    (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

TS method:

```
keyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const pattern = /[0-9]/;
    const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
        // invalid character, prevent input
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input (keypress)="keyPress($event)" 
    type="number" 
    pattern="[0-9]*" 
    placeholder="Enter new PIN" 
    inputmode="numeric" 
    style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"></input>
```

Here the pattern in html is not needed because you are restricted to type another character than 0-9.

Good luck!

Comment: Why did you add keypress inside brackets? What is this syntax? 
This is confusing me, because () are supposed to be used wih `@Output()` properties.

Comment: It is an Event like click, keydown, change, and should be like that to bind a component method. Output is an EventEmiter, is the same.

Comment: The only error in the above code at this time is event).charCode really should be event.charCode, i.e. one character, ")", should be removed.  But StackOverflow says it's required to change at least 6 characters in a given edit.  So, essentially... you need to invent other changes that aren't in fact necessary... (?)

Answer (score 2):

To make a input field number only, you can do this. So you can use onkeypress  for another function.

```
 <input type="text"
    onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode === 8 || 
                                  event.keyCode === 46 ?
                                  true : !isNaN(Number(event.key))"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

We should use `KeyboardEvent` instead of event as a type of the input parameter of `keyPress`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for another way of determining if a specific key is pressed (like the space key), you can use:

```
grabText(event){
    if(event.code === 'Space'){
        console.log('PRESSED SPACE');
        ...  
    }

}
```